# How does a hidden unit in a Boltzmann Machine differ from a hidden unit in a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I was reading about Boltzmann Machines, and I found this:

*The state of a hidden unit in a Boltzmann Machine is a random variable, but in a Neural Net it is a deterministic function of the inputs.*

Why is the hidden unit a random variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because output from the hidden layer is a vector with probabilities where each state between 0 and 1. Using these probabilities we can sample binary vector. Which means that the same input will produce different outcomes. This property make output a random variable.